# MySQL Edit form is overwriting all database entries

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have 3 pages: search.html. search.php, and edit.php

I also have new.php which I can use to create an entry into my MySQL database, and it works perfectly, I can view the data and it's where it's supposed to be. Then, I have search.html and search.php which I use to do a very basic search of the database, and it again works perfectly.

Then, in the results (on search.php) I have an edit link that launches edit.php with the data beside the returned results, and it loads edit.php along with the correct data. So I think I'm ok up to this point. But then, when I edit my form and click submit, it overwrites every entry in the database, instead of just the entry that I initially tried to edit. Been messing with this for about an hour now and not sure where I've messed up. Code below:

**Search.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search the Database</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
  Search:
  <input type="text" name="term" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Search.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("myhost", "myuser","mypass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("mydb");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from mytable where fname like '%$term%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['fname'];
    echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['lname'];
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }

?>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php
function renderForm($id, $fname, $lname)
 {
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
  <h1>Edit Entry</h1>
  <Label>First Name/Organization </label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
  <Label>Attn. </label>
  <input type="text" name="attn" value="<?php echo $attn; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 }

 include('settings.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $fname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']));
 $lname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']));

 if ($fname == '' || $lname == '')
 {

 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 renderForm($id, $fname, $lname);
 }
 else
 {

 mysql_query("UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 header("Location: index.html"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 {

 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if($row)
 {

 $fname = $row['fname'];
 $lname = $row['lname'];

 renderForm($id, $fname, $lname, '');
 }
 else

 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else

 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I'm still quite new to MySQL so your help is greatly appreciated. I selected Fahim's answer as correct because he explained more so, but I value everyone's input and up voted you all. I flagged Col. Sharpnel's comment as off topic and unhelpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mistake

you have `mysql_query("UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname'")`

What it means is you want to set new first and last name for all entries....

### Learning

Whenever we update we provide condition for which id you want to change...

so your query should be

`mysql_query("UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE id=$id")`

For `UPDATE` it should be always

```
UPDATE myTable
SET field1=new_value_1, field2=new_value_2, .....
WHERE condition
```

### Good Luck

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your SQL statement in edit.php is missing a WHERE clause:

You have:

```
"UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname'"
```

Probably should be:

```
"UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE id=$id"
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the where clause with the `$id?`

Your query should be

`mysql_query("UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' **WHERE id=$id**")`

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE entries SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE id=$id")
```

You need to specify which record to update, otherwise it will update all the records

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to filter your **UPDATE** Clause. You should add a `WHERE` in your statement.

```
UPDATE `entries` 
SET `fname`='$fname', `lname` = '$lname' 
WHERE `id`=$id
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to update specific row data value and for that your all data going to overwrite...

```
WHERE `id`=$id
```

So your Correct update code is ...

```
$update ="UPDATE `entries` SET `fname`='$fname', `lname` = '$lname' WHERE `id`=$id";
```